# Dump contents of Excel sheet using webpage into a database

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, apache-poi

I have developed a stand-alone utility which dumps content of Excel sheet into an Oracle Database table.

I made use of Swing and POI jars.

Now i have to do the same in web environment. That is user visits my url https:www.example.com browses for an excel file and once click on submit , the content in excel sheet should get added to servers database ??

How can i go about doing this. Here i will have to first send the excel sheet data to server how is it achievable ??  Can i do it using Spring framework more easily ? Open to suggestions

Please help.

Comment: I am amusing that "you want to upload excel file from browser and process excel and insert data to DB" What you have to use is multipath request implemented servlets or struts or spring web to upload files. if you user multipath request you can upload from any system using URL, if you dont use that multipath request you cant upload from any other system only you can upload by localhost.

Comment: I believe Using swing you upload the excel document, here servlet or struts or spring will do that job for you.

Comment: Since you're using Spring, check out Spring File Upload